Is Tr(F) + E_ZZ = E_tot in DFT?
I am working with a DFT package (pyscf in this case). Assume $F_\text{dft}$ is the fock matrix of dft and $\rho$ is the one particle reduced density matrix. I have never seen a result claiming that $\text{Tr}(F_\text{DFT} \rho) + E_{ZZ} = E_\text{tot}$ in any of my dft text books. However when I do the calculation of $\text{Tr}(F_\text{DFT} \rho)$, I am getting the electronic energy (or within 2% of it).
Is $\text{Tr}(F_\text{DFT} \rho) + E_{ZZ} = E_\text{tot}$ a general result which is true for DFT?

It is not a correct result. At least if you assume fock, $F$ is the usual sum of the core hamiltonian ( $F = -(1/2)\nabla_i^2 + V_\text{ext} + V_\text{h} + V_\text{xc}$) with the effective potential. Here $\nabla_i^2$ is a one-particle laplacian. On the contrary, the trace of fock with rdm1 is a sum of kohn-sham eigenvalues (the quantity is sometimes referred to as the 'band energy').
However, you can define a operator $H$ such that $\text{Tr}(H \rho) + E_\text{zz} = E_\text{tot}$. You could call it the hamiltonian matrix if you want, but in mainstream DFT theory, the energy doesn't come from an operator but instead a functional. In fact, DFT doesn't have 'one hamiltonian' operator even though lots of people seem to believe so. When you read about 'DFT hamiltonians' in Chinese papers, you might feel puzzled because they don't specify which operator they are talking about.
